# Downloading problems with excel file size in React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, frontend

I am working with Spring-3.9.3, creating Excel files and trying to download them from React. The code works fine with small file sizes (50kb), more than this means no response from the React localhost web.

I don't know how to fix the problem as I have no idea if the error comes from Spring or React library.

The code comes from a tutorial that you can find here:
https://rieckpil.de/howto-up-and-download-files-with-react-and-spring-boot/

```
//react code from react
class App extends Component {
  downloadExcel = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/files')
      .then(response => {
        const filename =  response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1];
        response.blob().then(blob => {
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          let a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = filename;
          a.click();
      });
   });
  }  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App-intro">
        <h3>Download an excel file</h3>
        <button onClick={this.downloadExcel}>Download</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here there is the Spring code that I am using:

```
//spring
@RestController
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/files")
@CrossOrigin(value = {"*"}, exposedHeaders = {"Content-Disposition"})
public class FileBoundary{


    @GetMapping
    public void getEntitiesXLS(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception, IOException, InvalidFormatException{     

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Contacts");

            //create the excel file with Apache POI library

            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"tickets.xlsx\"");
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

I can see the request in Spring console but there is no response in the React web. Anyone knows a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was the timeout response of the micro.